How to derive the ODE from the EOM of vortex?
In the Lagrangian mode we have the equation of motion
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}&=j^\nu. \\
 D_{\mu }D^{\mu}\phi +\mu^{2}\phi-\lambda(\phi^{*}\phi)\phi &=0.
\end{align}
Since we have the
\begin{align}
\phi(r,\theta)&=ve^{i\theta}F(r)\\A_i(r,\theta)&=-\frac1{er}\epsilon_{ij}n_jA(r)
\end{align}
How to derive the following ODE
\begin{align}-\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{dA}{dr}\right)-2e^{2}v^{2}\frac{F^{2}}{r}(1-A)=0,\\-\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dF}{dr}\right)+\lambda v^{2}rF(F^{2}-1)+\frac{F}{r}(1-A)^{2}=0.
\end{align}
Where does the $(1-A)^{2}$ come from?

Should be from the A hidden in the covariant derivatives

But  it seems that the second equation cannot give the quadratic component.

I think it does: (Dropping all constants one finds:) $D_\mu D^\mu \sim \partial^2 - A_\mu A^\mu $. Now $A_\mu A^\mu \sim \epsilon_{ij} \epsilon_{jk} A_i A_k \sim A^2$. Using $\epsilon^{ij} \epsilon_{jk} = \delta^i_k$

I think so, thx.
